# ETH node don't change account balance for some reason

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum

I am install eth node and wait while all blockchain will be actual. I have created address with  `personal_newAccount` and try to send some money to this account.
Address - `0x11754F088d2C1D679D49D89dB402b87c609baB08`
https://etherscan.io/address/0x11754f088d2c1d679d49d89db402b87c609bab08
I sent and nothing come. I am unlock account(for sure) and try(sent money) again, but nothing come again.

```
eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 12800589,
  highestBlock: 12800705,
  knownStates: 0,
  pulledStates: 0,
  startingBlock: 12798108
}
```

and i can fount transaction by hash in my node but i have zero value on balance and as you can see  there is some OUT transaction(i did't do it). What can be wrong?

Comment: I am run node with 
```geth --cache=4096 --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpcport 8545 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "web3,personal,admin,debug,db,net,eth,miner,rpc,txpool" --datadir /mnt/eth/eth/ --allow-insecure-unlock```

Comment: ```Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!

instance: Geth/v1.10.4-stable-aa637fd3/linux-amd64/go1.16.4
coinbase: 0xa48a480d86750093f51a7a4b21d0905fb6bbbef4
```

Answer (score 0):

I had sucurity issue, someone stolen my etn coins when it come to wallet address. One big advise from me - if you want to install eth node on server you need to protect the server at first. In my case I did in reverse and got a big problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).